# Are theses perfect? readers opinions on honest mistakes? (whatever degree)

Tags: publications, thesis, degree, errors-erratum

I used to have a big concern for a little statistical mistake in my thesis (which wont be published), and now I have overcome that fear.

During that time of fear, my parents told me that all the thesis have mistakes. Even teachers, friends, everyone told me that thesis aren't perfect.

what do you think? How can a reader verify that a mistake was a honest mistake and not manipulation on purpose?

Comment: A perfect thesis is a done thesis.

Comment: The question in the title is very different than the question in the last paragraph. What specific question do you want answered?

Comment: I prefer the last one

Comment: No one will read the whole thing. Few will ever even look at it. Even heavily peer reviewed journal articles have rampant mistakes; you should always re-derive complex results for yourself before trying to build on them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many theses have mistakes. Some even have intentional errors. How a given work is judged depends on many factors, too numerous to list. If it was an honest answer then some rework will lead to a more valid result. If that valid result is essentially the same as what you wrote, it will almost certainly be dismissed as an oversight.

But you can't change the past. It is what it is. You could, perhaps, produce a publication based on your thesis work in which you cite the thesis and correct the error.

Ultimately a reader can accept your work as acceptable if not perfect or reject it. You have no control over that. Someone who tries to reproduce your results and comes up with very different results will probably write about it in their own publication. You should be the one to do this instead.

Comment: How can someone try to reproduce my results if the data is froma company and the thesis will not be published?

Comment: From the description of the problem and your results. This assumes it is "seen" by people. If it is never seen there is no issue whatever as long as your advisor and the university has accepted it.

Comment: My fear on those dark days was that maybe someday someone will have access to thesis and try to revoke my degree.

Comment: Not. Going. To. Happen. It is incredibly rare. But think about a follow up publication.

Comment: What is a follow up publication?

Comment: Any paper of yours on the same topic, in which you cite the thesis.

Comment: Can you explain why one would include intentional errors?

Comment: @holla, If someone wants to "prove" a false thing, then data can be falsified, for example. Scientific misconduct.

Comment: @Buffy: oh, okay. Didn't think of this. Sorry.

Comment: @holla, probably because you are honest. ;)

Comment: @Buffy Intentional errors are a very stupid thing to do, if the topic is of any consequence (and thus likely to be further pursued by others). Jan Hendrik Schoen found that out to his cost (albeit, to be fair, the errors probably were unintentional during his thesis write-up and only then started becoming intentional). If someone goes for intentional errors, it should be in a topic nobody cares about. But then, why do the thesis?

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Buffy said, perhaps, if you can't publish the company specific data reanalysis, you could do some paper on the general flaw.  (e.g. "regressing presmoothed data artificially inflates the apparent rsq")  Or even a different dataset that you analyze properly and then put some warning about how a mistake could be made and then cite*/correct the other paper (even in a footnote...you don't even need to redisplay the data for this sort of "rowback" correction).  But at least you are still getting SOME correction out there.

*And yes, you can cite unpublished work.

Comment: I dont want to publish my work, I just want to have a cool life.

Comment: It's probably fine.  If it bugs you a lot, then figure out some method to put a correction out there (like Buffy suggests).  If it bugs you less (than the work of doing a publication to sneak the rowback in) than leave it as is.  You're probably fine.  Nobody will read it. I bet even your company doesn't rely on it.  And gawd knows there are a lot of company techreports with mistakes in them.